# What is the chemical structure of myosin?

Tags: biochemistry, homework

What is the chemical structure of myosin? Specfically, what functional groups or monomers are they made of?

Comment: What have you already learned in searching?

Comment: I just know the functions and the categories of it.:( Based on the research, I know that it is a motor protein and acts with actin to perform muscle contraction. Also that some types of myosin performs other  activities like phagocytosis or transporting vesicles  and that there are powered by ATP hydrolysis. I only have basic knowledge of chem and bio but I assume that since it is a protein it is made of amino methyl or carboxyl groups.

Comment: Ok. Why do you want to know the chemical structure? What will it tell you? With proteins, we don't usually talk in terms of chemical structure, but as chains of amino acids. Really you should probably learn more about amino acids first based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm  doing a project related to macromolecules, and for me it is myosin.  The thing that concerns me is that there is one part asking about the chemical structure (functional groups ,monomer, and polar regions). I researched and read some article for hours. I understand how it functions and impacts the body but I could't really grasp  how it is chemically made and I feel like I'm lost:(  This sounds like a stupid question but would you mind recommending me how to approach this kind of research, like what concepts I could know for better understanding?

Comment: Probably the Wikipedia pages on proteins and amino acids would help you - you probably also have a textbook with similarly helpful descriptions. You kind of need to understand those basics before trying to understand the structure of a particular protein.